# PC doesn't recognize my PCI-E graphic card anymore

Tags: motherboard, pci-express

I've been using an Ati HD4670 graphic card mounted on an Asus M2NPV-VM mobo for months. One month ago PC started switching off about 1 minute after booting. So I removed the graphic card and reactivated the onboard integrated graphics: PC worked like a charm. 
Recently I tried another graphic card (Ati HD4350) on the same PC, but mobo didn't recognize it either (BIOS is set to give priority on PCI-E card... so it should work...)

Any suggestion? Is it possible the PCI-E slot has broken, but all the rest is still working?
Thx

Answer (score 1):

Try it in another PCI-e slot if you have one - it is indeed possible that the slot is defective.

EDIT: It's also possible that the PCI-e power connector (I haven't used either of these cards but I believe they require the power connector) isn't providing proper voltage.

Comment: Thanks Shinrai, but: I don't have another PCI-E slot on my board and both PCI-E cards don't have a power connector

Comment: I'm sorry to hear that.  Barring another machine that you can test it with there's really no way to be sure...